# Rounded Corners Buttons GTK#

Tags: gtk#

I want to find out how to change the shape of a button (using gtk sharp). The default shape for the button widget is a rectangle, but I want my buttons to have rounded edges. Is there a way to do this without using the mono-cairo reference?

Comment: I did this by instead creating a gtk image of a rounded button(using graphics path) and adding it to a gtk eventbox.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your buttons style classes:

```
<style>
    <class name="circular"/>
</style>
```

See e.g.

https://code.puri.sm/Librem5/libhandy/src/master/src/hdy-dialer-button.ui#L8